# NSFileManager Can't retrieve files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In the method transmitData, the NSArray files is coming up nil.  Where is the problem in my code?  I save a file (we hit [file writeToURL: fileURL atomically: YES]) and then we call transmitData, but cannot retrieve the files.

```
#import "FileManagerService.h"
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h"
@implementation FileManagerService
SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(FileManagerService);

#define SAVEVOTER @"SV"
#define SAVESCRIPT @"SS"

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

-(void)saveFile:(NSData*)file:(NSString*)dataType
{
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *fileURL;
NSString *fileName;

if (dataType == DATA_SAVE_VOTER)
{
    fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@01",SAVEVOTER];
    fileURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    int fID = 0;

    while ([manager fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL absoluteString]]) 
    {
        fID++;

        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",SAVEVOTER,fID];
        fileURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    }

}
else if (dataType == DATA_SAVE_SCRIPT)
{
    fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@01",SAVESCRIPT];
    fileURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    int fID = 0;

    while ([manager fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL absoluteString]]) 
    {
        fID++;

        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",SAVESCRIPT,fID];
        fileURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    }

}


[file writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
}


-(void)transmitData
{
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]absoluteString] error:NULL];

if (files == nil || [files count] <= 0)
{
    NSLog(@"No files to transmit");
    return;
}

for (id file in files) 
{ 
    NSData * dt = file;
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"DataContents: %@",str);
}
}

@end
```

EDIT:
Upon more testing :

```
fileName = @"testfile";
    fileURL = [[self    applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSLog(@"URL1: %@",[fileURL absoluteString]);
```

My log is coming up Null.  So I cant retrieve files because I am obviously saving with a null file location....why is this happening?

FIXED:

So I have no idea why, but [file writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES] does NOT work and [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileURL
                                            contents:file
                                          attributes:nil]; 
does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPath];
}
```

and

```
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]path] error:NULL];
```

Comment: My bad, don't use absoluteString. Edited my answer.

Comment: Looks like I get a valid url if I test on the device and not the sim...but it still can't retrieve the files

Comment: Are you sure there are files at that path on the simulator?

Comment: URL: /var/mobile/Applications/2B2BA596-38BF-4D74-881C-72F2B175ACC8/Documents/SV01

I only get this url if I save to the device and not the sim.  But my code still wont read the files.  I'm expecting the files array to take each file and put it as an element of the array as an NSData.  Is this wrong?

Comment: contentsOf... does not return file objects. It returns names of files & folders inside the directory.